# IBM Cloud Watson Visual Recognition image classification.. Error in uploading file

Tags: ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

Through my IBM Cloud account, I have registered a Watson Visual Recognition service.
Then I tried using their API to upload an image '`fruitbowl.jpg`' to my bucket associated with this service and then get some analysis on that image.

I have tried the code available at [link](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/ee1d0b44-0fce-4cf6-8545-e1dc961d0668/view?access_token=c0489b861ab65f63be7e3c5ce962003a2a0197660e67ecb140c477c2e11b5fe3)

Till the API and bucket validation, code works fine but throws error

```
"`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fruitbowl.jpg'" at: 

cos.upload_file(Filename='fruitbowl.jpg',Bucket=credentials['BUCKET'],Key='fruitbowl.jpg')
```

I can see that this file is available in my bucket.

Code:

```
from ibm_botocore.client import Config
    import ibm_boto3
    def download_file_cos( credentials, local_file_name, key ):
        cos = ibm_boto3.client( service_name            = 's3',
                                ibm_api_key_id          = credentials['IBM_API_KEY_ID'],
                                ibm_service_instance_id = credentials['IAM_SERVICE_ID'],
                                ibm_auth_endpoint       = credentials['IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT'],
                                config=Config(signature_version = 'oauth'),
                                endpoint_url            = credentials['ENDPOINT'] )
        try:
            cos.upload_file( Filename='fruitbowl.jpg',Bucket=credentials['BUCKET'],Key='fruitbowl.jpg')
        except Exception as e:
            print( Exception, e )
        else:
            print( 'File Downloaded' )
```

My current directory for IBM cloud notebook is

Comment: I assume that you set the correct credentials and the correct bucket name in the credentials object, correct?

Comment: Yes, credentials and bucket name are correct

Comment: The code is for UPLOADING a file. Why is it already in your bucket? Are you specifying that bucket or directory correctly?

Comment: Where to find the directory path for the files that are already present in S3 Bucket since this needs to be mentioned in Notebook of IBM cloud.